# Django - Redirect page slug to detailview - shortening urls

Tags: python, django, redirect

Alright, I have a simple setup with pages which belong to certain categories.

In my urls I have

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.PageByCategoryView.as_view(), name='page_by_category'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:page_slug>/', views.PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page_detail'),
```

So for example;

> www.mywebsite.com/activities/cycling/

points to the correct detailview for a page about cycling.

Now I thought It would be nice if we could shorten the url like;

> www.mywebsite.com/cycling/

So I wrote the following view;

```
def redirect_with_category(request, page_slug):
    '''
    This redirect view points to the canonical url
    '''
    page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=page_slug)
    return redirect(page, permanent=True)
```

The urls.py are like this;

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.PageByCategoryView.as_view(), name='page_by_category'),
path('<slug:page_slug>/', views.redirect_with_category, name='page_detail_redirect'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:page_slug>/', views.PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page_detail'),
```

And now we get into trouble, even though the redirect works. Django stops trying to solve the category_slug if it can't find a match.

Somehow to get this to work, Django should try to resolve the next path it it does not find a match within category_slug.

Apparently Django throws an error according to the documentation; "[or if an exception is raised during any point in this process, Django invokes an appropriate error-handling view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/)"

Is there anyway we can solve this? Can Django be forced to look for the next matching results if it doesn't find a matching slug in the first url?

So I want to redirect;

> www.mywebsite.com/cycling/ TO: www.mywebsite.com/activities/cycling/

Comment: Of course, since any slug will match `<slug:category_slug>`, hence the second url will never "fire".

Comment: I'd recommend just using a single `path('<slug:any_slug>/',[...]` and then in the view you could to a `try: except` to look for category first, then look for pages if no category is found.

Comment: Ben, this would be a valid option. Although I would like to keep the category within the url for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because the `path('<slug:page_slug>/, …)` will never "fire", since each request you make is "captured" by the `path('<slug:category_slug>/, …)` if you make *fully* overlapping paths, the last one will never be triggered. In general it is better to make paths that do *not* overlap *at all*, since that means that for the overlap, a certain path is not accessible and one might intend to make that accessible.

You thus should do the matching in the `PageByCategoryView` view, and if that gives a "hit", thus perform the `redirect`, you can do that for example by overriding the `dispatch` method (or `get` if you only wish to redirect GET requests).

```
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

class PageByCategoryView(ListView):

    # …

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
        except Http404:
            page = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=self.kwargs['category_slug'])
            return redirect(page)
```

We thus first aim to handle the request properly by calling the `super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)` method. If that returns a 404, we try to find a `Page` with the `slug` being equal to the `category_slug` and redirect to there. If that fails as well, a 404 will be returned.

Comment: Goodmorning! Tried your suggestion, just wondering if the "Http404" after except should be there? I'm currently using it like except: .. (Without the Http404).

Comment: @KevinD.: usually a blanket exception is a serious antipattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_hiding